# Why does my last index have a value when it shouldn't have one?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, indexing, integer

I am trying to shift all elements in my array to the left by 1, I am trying to remove the element 3 at index 0 from my array but the output I receive is completely different than what I expect. I don't understand why I receive this output.

The output I expect to receive is [2,2,3,0] I expect a zero on the last index because I shifted all elements to the left so there would be no value shifted to the last index. But I instead received [2,2,3,3]. I don't understand why a 3 is in the last index?

```
int [] nums = {3,2,2,3};
int length = nums.length;

for (int j = 1; j < length; j++) {

   nums [j - 1] = nums [j];
}

return nums.length;
```

Comment: Why do you expect that the last 3 magically becomes a 0? Array values don't change, when no one changes them.

Comment: You need to assign `0` explicitly to the last index because it's already occupied and therefore it doesn't have the default value any more.

Comment: Yes, I accidentally did the wrong syntax, I thought because I shifted all the elements to the left by 1 the last index would have a zero?

Comment: You never assign a value to nums[3], as j-1 only goes up to 2.
Try to run it step by step in a debugger, and look at the final iteration in particular.

Comment: No, because you don't actually _shift_ anything here, you _copy_ values from one index to another. The final result just looks like a shift. And since you copy those values the last 3 stays where it is.

Comment: oh thanks, I just realized my mistake in assuming it would be a 0.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, I just set the last one to 0:

```
int[] nums = {3,2,2,3};
int length = nums.length;

for (int j = 1; j < length; j++) {
    nums [j - 1] = nums [j];
}

nums[nums.length - 1] = 0;

for (int number : nums) {
    System.out.print(number);
}
```

I set the last number to 0 because you only changed the indices 0, 1 and 2 with your for-loop so that the last index, i.e. index 3, keeps the value 3.

So you get this: 2230.